# NaN or blank value for calculated JS var

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have the following javascript:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeBet(parseFloat(bet)) {
var moneyline = parseFloat(<?php echo json_encode($win) ?>);
var gain = parseFloat(bet * moneyline);
document.getElementById("PotentialGain").value = gain;
}
</script>
```

The php variable $win is successfully var_dump'ed as a float. When the variable `gain` = `bet`, PotentialGain displays the user input from BetAmount as expected. Here is my echo'ed php code:

```php
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>type="text" name="BetAmount[]" id="BetAmount" onkeyup="changeBet(this.value);" ></td></tr><tr><td>Potential Gain:<input type="text" name="PotentialGain[]"  id="PotentialGain" ></td></tr><tr><td><input type="Submit" name="send" value="Submit"></td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

However, I want gain(which is inputted as the PotentialGain value) to be the user input `bet` * the var `moneyline`.

The result is NaN. Is there a var that I am not parsing correctly to display the correct numerical value of gain?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `function changeBet(parseFloat(bet)){...` - parameters don't work like this.

Comment: just a note, this is just javascript, not jquery

Comment: @ahren thanks, i added that afterwards and the result was blank. Without the `parseFloat` in `function changeBet(parseFloat(bet)){...` the result is NaN

Comment: Aside from the error pointed out in the first comment, you're also passing a JSON string (JSON is *not* an object) into `parseFloat`. If you're always expecting it to be a number there's no need for that. If you do need to JSON encode it. You'll need to use `JSON.parse` first to make it an actual javascript object. Then point to the number like `objName.someNumber`.

Comment: `parseFloat(<?php echo json_encode($win) ?>` is useless as long as `$win` does not contain a string literal. If you output a number already, let it be a number. `parseFloat` only works on strings.

Comment: Inside `changeBet()`, add `console.log(bet, moneyline)` after all the `parseFloat()` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final javascript that I used:

```html
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeBet(bet) {
var moneyline = <?php echo $win ?>;
var gain = (bet * moneyline).toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("PotentialGain").value = gain;
}
</script>
</html>
```

My final notes are: 1. To remember to place the javascript function after the code with your php caclculations. 2. Thanks to everyone who clarified `parseFloat` is not necessary if you know the var is a int (or double in my case). 3. Thanks to everyone who clarified `parseFloat` did not belong in the function parameter.

Hopefully this helps others out!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the incorrect syntax in this line:

```
function changeBet(parseFloat(bet)) {
```

you need to pass a **parameter** to the function, like this:

```
function changeBet(bet) {
```

Then, when you *call* the function, you can evaluate whatever argument you want to send through parseFloat:

```
changeBet(parseFloat(strBet));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't put a function call where a parameter name is expected.

```
function changeBet(bet) {
    bet = parseFloat(bet);
    // rest of code
}
```